# django: how to display choices in form's ChoiceField depending on the current user's data

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the following form with 4 fields:

```
from django import forms
from django.apps import apps

from .models import Task

CustomUser = apps.get_model('users', 'CustomUser')

students = CustomUser.objects.filter(status='student')
students_choices = [(student.username, student) for student in students]


class AddTaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('title', 'description', 'deadline', 'student')
        widgets = {
            'deadline': forms.SelectDateWidget(),
        }

    student = forms.ChoiceField(choices=students_choices)
```

The "student" field will display the choices with all users with status "student". But what if I want the queryset to be:

```
students = CustomUser.objects.filter(status='student', username__in=user.students.split())
```

How can I get user here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, do not do the query on module level:

```
students = CustomUser.objects.filter(status='student')
```

This line will execute only one time (at the application start).

So to answer to your question:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['student'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=((student.id, student.username) for student in custom_queryset))
```

And this is of course the AddTaskForm **init**

Wonder if this is some kind of a student task ;)
Happy coding.

Comment: I've tried this before, but got an error because I didn't know that super() must be called before the assignment. Thanks anyway.